# How to fix the error procedure expects parameter '@parameters' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic

I'm trying to use a stored procedure to display the results of a table, and an associated table or recent changes to the database.  The stored procedure is:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set NOCOUNT ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MKTG_Current]( @added smalldatetime OUTPUT, @named varchar(50) OUTPUT)
AS

DECLARE @pDate smalldatetime;
DECLARE @AIID int;
DECLARE @Table varchar(50);
DECLARE @Bork nvarchar(350);
SET @pDate = GETDATE()


SELECT @Table=[Table], @AIID=AIID, @added=date_added  FROM MKTG_Recent WHERE date_added > DATEDIFF(day, date_added, DATEADD(DD, 30, @pDate))
SET @named = @Table
SET @Bork = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Table) + ' WHERE AIID= ' + cast(@AIID as varchar(100))

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Bork, @added OUTPUT, @named OUTPUT


SELECT @added, @named
```

It's supposed to return to items in addition to the results from the select statement.  There are no inputs to the stored procedure.  The stored procedure compiles fine in SQL Management Studio (2008), but the page returns an error:
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'

Procedure expects parameter '@parameters' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'. 
index.asp, line 61

Line 61 of the page is in bold:

```
  dim Objrs, cmd
  set Objrs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
  set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  conn.Open strConnect
  set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
  cmd.CommandText="MKTG_Current"
  cmd.CommandType=adCmdStoredProc
  cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@added", 135, 2)
  cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@named", 200, 2, 50)
Line 61 **set Objrs = cmd.Execute**
  name_of_table = cmd.Parameters("@named")
  added = cmd.Parameters("@added")
```

I'm of the impression that this is caused by a SQL code error, but I'm not seeing it. A quick check of the Objrs.state is returning a 0, which means the problem definitely lies in the SQL code.  For the life of me, I can't identify why this error is being generated.

Comment: check whether you have the same SP but with another parameters list (see not in dbo schema)

Comment: Another comment - if more than one table has been updated in MKTG_Recent in your WHERE clause timeframe, do you know which one you're going to get? I sure don't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this answer, I will try to recreate the issue that you mentioned in the question and will also explain how I resolved this.

First, let's create two tables named `dbo.MKTG_Recent` and `dbo.Table_1` using the scripts under **Create Tables Script** section. I created these tables based on some assumptions that I made using the data provided in the question. Using the script, the table `dbo.MKTG_Recent` will be populated with 1 record.

Next, create the stored procedure named `dbo.MKTG_Current` using the script provided under **Create Stored Procedure Script** section.

If, we try to execute the stored procedure with EXEC command as `EXEC MKTG_Current null, null`, the error message **`Msg 214, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@parameters' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.`** will be thrown. Refer screenshot **#1**

After reading through [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) about the usage of the procedure [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), I found that the second parameter of the stored procedure defines the types of the output parameters and it has to be a Unicode string. So, I modified the stored procedure by providing the second parameter as Unicode string by prefixing with N. Refer screenshot **#2** for the stored procedure change.

Screenshot **#3** shows the output of the stored procedure `dbo.MKTG_Current` after making the changes. The stored procedure will produce two outputs. One for the query statement in the variable @Bork that is being passed to sp_executesql and the other output corresponds to the SELECT statement that displays the OUTPUT variables.

Based on the requirement, I am not sure if you even need to call sp_executesql, you can write the stored procedure as shown under **Simplified Stored Procedure** Section. I could be wrong because I don't fully understand the requirement. Screenshot **#4** shows output of the simplified stored procedure. *SELECT* statement is not required because the values are being passed through the *OUTPUT* parameters. I have included the *SELECT* statement only to show the query output.

Hope this points you in the right direction.

**Create Tables Script:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MKTG_Recent](
    [Table] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [AIID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [date_added] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [AIID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [added] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [named] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.MKTG_Recent ([Table], AIID, date_added) 
VALUES ('Table_1', 1, '2011-08-01')
GO
```

**Create Stored Procedure Script:**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MKTG_Current]
(       @added  SMALLDATETIME   OUTPUT
    ,   @named  VARCHAR(50)     OUTPUT
)
AS

DECLARE @pDate  SMALLDATETIME;
DECLARE @AIID   INT;
DECLARE @Table  VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @Bork   NVARCHAR(350);

SET     @pDate  = GETDATE()

SELECT  @Table  = [Table]
    ,   @AIID   = AIID
    ,   @added  = date_added  
FROM    dbo.MKTG_Recent 
WHERE   date_added > DATEDIFF(day, date_added, DATEADD(DD, 30, @pDate))

SET @named  = @Table
SET @Bork   = ' SELECT  * 
                FROM    ' + QUOTENAME(@Table) + ' 
                WHERE   AIID= ' + CAST(@AIID AS VARCHAR(100))

EXECUTE sp_executesql   @Bork
                    ,   @added OUTPUT
                    ,   @named OUTPUT

SELECT  @added
    ,   @named 
GO
```

**Simplified Stored Procedure:**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MKTG_Current]
(       @added  SMALLDATETIME   OUTPUT
    ,   @named  VARCHAR(50)     OUTPUT
)
AS

DECLARE @Table  VARCHAR(50);

SELECT  @named  = [Table]
    ,   @added  = date_added  
FROM    dbo.MKTG_Recent 
WHERE   date_added > DATEDIFF(day, date_added, DATEADD(DD, 30, GETDATE()))

SELECT  @added AS added
    ,   @named AS named 
GO
```

**Screenshots:**

**#1:** Execution showing the error message

[image: Error_Message]

**#2:** Change made to the stored procedure

[image: Modified_SP]

**#3:** Stored procedure output after the changes

[image: Stored_procedure_output]

**#4:** Simplified stored procedure output

[image: Simplified_stored_procedure_output]

Answer (score 3):

You declared @Bork as `NVARCHAR`. So why do you say:

```
SET @Bork = 'SELECT ...';
```

? Should be:

```
SET @Bork = N'SELECT ...';
```

This is how we define `NVARCHAR` (Unicode) strings. The N stands for national. If you leave out that N prefix, `sp_executesql` assumes it is `VARCHAR`, and that leads to the error.

**EDIT** for Kieren

While technically yes, you *CAN* declare `NVARCHAR` literals without the N prefix, there are several reasons why you should never do so. One is to avoid the error that user873479 is receiving. Others are to ensure correct results. Some examples:

(A) Let's try `sp_executesql` with the N prefix and without. Even though there are no actual Unicode characters in the string, forgetting to put the N prefix when calling `sp_executesql` leads to the exact same error this question is about:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT 1';
EXEC sp_executesql 'SELECT 1';
```

Results

```
====
1
====
Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.
```

(B) Now let's try a very simple assignment of a Unicode character to an `NVARCHAR` variable. Notice how, without the N prefix, the actual value gets lost?

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(32) = 'Ǝ';
SELECT @x;
SET @x = N'Ǝ';
SELECT @x;
```

Results

```
====
?
====
Ǝ
```

(C) Now let's take it a step further. Let's put some Unicode data into a table:

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE(bar NVARCHAR(1));
INSERT @foo(bar) SELECT N'Ǝ';

-- now someone comes along looking for the row, without using N:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @foo WHERE bar = 'Ǝ';
```

Results

```
====
0
```

And I could come up with more examples where implicitly switching between CHAR/VARCHAR and NCHAR/NVARCHAR can turn seeks into scans, but I think error messages and incorrect results should be enough for now.

So sure, you can get away with declaring `NVARCHAR` literals without using the N prefix, but only if you're not calling procedures that expect `NVARCHAR`, and only if your data doesn't actually include any Unicode characters (in which case I would have to wonder why you bothered to use `NVARCHAR` in the first place).

Comment: That's not true, you can use literals without the N just fine with NVARCHAR types

Comment: Okay @Kieren, have you ***tried*** calling `EXEC sp_executesql 'SELECT 1';`? Do you have a better answer as to why the user is getting the error message described? Maybe you could read my updated answer and reconsider your down-vote.

Comment: `create procedure proc_ParamTest(@p1 nvarchar(200)) as
select @p1
go` / `proc_ParamTest 'Hello'` works just fine here.  As does `sp_helptext 'sp_executesql'` which told me that executesql is **'Internal'** and so probably a special case?  Even `sp_helptext` which told me itself that it takes an `nvarchar` param and took my literal fine.  I don't have a better idea, no.  But the OP isn't calling `sp_executesql` with a `varchar` literal either.

Comment: The user isn't calling sp_helptext, they are calling sp_executesql. Yes, it is a special case, but did you read the rest of my edited answer? Did you try passing some actual Unicode data to your proc_ParamTest?

Comment: Yes I did read it, and I'll say it again, it's not true that you have to prefix literals with `N` for this.  You need to prefix if the literal contains unicode characters, but that's not the issue here is it?  They are calling `sp_executesql` and passing it an `nvarchar` parameter, not a literal.  So how is that even relevant?

Comment: Kieren, I don't know how else to explain this to you. **DID YOU TRY** `EXEC sp_executesql 'SELECT 1';`? What happened? Error message, right? Then if you try `EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT 1';`, what happened? No error message, right? How am I missing that this is relevant?

Comment: And by the way, the other answer is right, the `sp_executesql` needs a second parameter describing the parameter names and types that follow as additional parameters.  Nothing to do with any of this .

Comment: That may be true, but it doesn't make it good practice to declare `NVARCHAR` variables and then assign literals without the N prefix. Once again, if you're using `NVARCHAR` but none of your data contains Unicode characters, why are you wasting half of your space? You should just be using `VARCHAR`. I'll state that if you're going to use `NVARCHAR`, you should use it correctly everywhere. I flagged your other rude comment - if you can't have a discussion without dropping F-bombs then I have no interest.

Comment: Aaron - Hah, a nice kid's playground "I'm telling on you" attitude in response to a word (nay, !BOMB!) that I used out of exasperation that you weren't reading my comments and suggesting I was stupid.  Obviously, I have discussions all day every day with people without having to underline my frustration with a naughty word (nay, !BOMB!), because very few people are insistent with such determination and irrelevance.  Regardless, many thanks for admitting you were wrong, and thanks to you, a 9-year old SQL developer won't be slightly possibly offended if they read these comments.  Bravo.

Comment: I was wrong about which parameter to sp_executesql was causing the error in this specific case, sorry about that. I did post within a couple of minutes of the question being posted, and have seen this exact thing many times before. In any case, if you think "educating" people that they should not bother with the N prefix on `NVARCHAR` string literals is a good idea, then YOU are the one who is wrong.